# What is the opposite of Flask's `init_app`? (Flask app teardown)

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a Flask extension that needs to create a temporary folder when its `init_app`-method is called. I'm planning to use Python's built-in `tempfile.mkdtemp()` – however, I need to remove the temporary directory when the Flask app is stopped/torn down.

What is the correct way to do this?
I'm thinking there should be some sort of inverse of the `init_app`-method.

Comment: Usually a Flask app is not stopped. It stops to handle requests and terminated with it when the flask server goes down.

Comment: Is this a flask extension for public consumption or just something for internal use?

Comment: It's an extension for https://github.com/mgood/flask-debugtoolbar, and I will publish on Github (and PyPI if possible) – so yes to the public consumption part

Answer (score 1):

There is no teardown; generally Flask servers are expected to run 'forever'.

Leave it to the OS to delete the temporary directory or register an [`atexit` handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) to clean up any such directories.

Note that it depends on your WSGI server forking model on how safe this is going to be. Some servers fork child processes *after* loading your Python module, so any globals are shared between these processes. If you created your temporary directory at the global level (not in a Flask `before_first_request` hook) then you could end up with child processes that all share the same temporary directory, but each child being reaped triggering an `atexit` handler. You may need to code defensively for this case.

Comment: But in a development environment where I'm starting and stopping the server a lot  – `python app.py`, and then `Ctrl-C` after a while – I would be creating a lot of "leaking" temporary directories.

Comment: @qff: then use atexit to clean up. But a lot of temp directories is hardly a problem; your OS will still clean these up periodically (and sometimes more often if you ran low on temp space).